# Read line from file every clock in verilog or systemverilog

Tags: verilog, simulation, system-verilog

I would like to test a module which accepts numbers from file every clock cycle and the data required is too long. I’m not able to store the complete file in memory so I need to feed the data to I_data every clock cycle from a file.

Is there any way I can do it using verilog or systemverilog?

Nutshell: read one line at posedge of every clock all the way to the end of file.

Comment: how big is your file and how many elements do you have to read?

Comment: I tried with $readmemh, it was kind of messy and i skipped it. Thank you guys for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dave suggested you can use fopen and fscanf for this purpose. A sample code will look like this:

```
integer outfile0; //file descriptor

initial begin

    outfile0=$fopen("file_to_be_read.txt","r");   //"r" means reading and "w" means writing
    //read line by line.
    while (! $feof(outfile0)) begin //read until an "end of file" is reached.
        $fscanf(outfile0,"%h\n",A); //scan each line and get the value as an hexadecimal, use %b for binary and %d for decimal.
        #10; //wait some time as needed.
    end 
    //once reading and writing is finished, close the file.
    $fclose(outfile0);
end
```

More explanation and detailed code is available [here](http://verilogcodes.blogspot.in/2017/11/file-reading-and-writingline-by-line-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is most definitely: yes.

Use `$fopen` to open the file, then `$fscanf` to read each line and store the values into variables.

There are many examples [out there](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/file-read-operations#reply-60039)

Comment: I did it with following code:

integer i,j,fd,rv;

initial
        begin
          fd = $fopen( "/home/haider/workspace/c/gen_file_1280x960.file", "r");
          for (i = 0; i < 960; i = i + 1)
            for (j = 0; j < 1280; j = j + 1)
              rv = $fscanf(fd, "%h", mem[i][j]);
end